# Where CFBundleName is being used

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

From this old question: [What's the difference between "bundle display name" and "bundle name" in cocoa application's info plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465792/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-display-name-and-bundle-name-in-cocoa-a)

It points to the official docs, which say:

> **CFBundleName**
>
> **CFBundleName** (String - iOS, OS X) identifies the short  name of the
>   bundle. This name should be less than 16 characters long and be 
>   suitable for displaying in the menu bar and the app’s Info window. You
>   can  include this key in the InfoPlist.strings file of an appropriate
>   .lproj   subdirectory to provide localized values for it. If you
>   localize this key,  you should also include the key
>   “CFBundleDisplayName.”

Can anyone tell how to show this name in iOS?

I was never able to show this value in my iPhone.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to show this name in iOS?"? Show it where?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like `CFBundleName` shows **anywhere** to the user, on iOS.  I believe I've seen documentation for Mac OS X (which obviously iOS inherits a lot of legacy infrastructure from), that says that the Bundle Name **is** used for something else ... I think it might have been the name in the upper Menu bar, or the lower Dock bar.  Neither thing exists in iOS, of course.

I also found [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557740/119114), which is now quite old (but with quite a few upvotes).  This answer claims that CFBundleName would be the name of the folder that the app is stored in.  So, for example, `CFBundleName = HelloWorld` should produce

```
+- HelloWorld.app
    - HelloWorldApplication
```

If the **Executable Name** was set to be `HelloWorldApplication`.  However, I just built a simple program and ran it on iOS 5.0, and the .app folder was **not** named equal to `CFBundleName`.  So, if it **ever** worked that way, it doesn't seem to any more.

I have seen quite a few references that say that `CFBundleName` should be left set to `${PRODUCT_NAME}` in Xcode, which is what I always do.  Not as a *technical* limitation, but as an Apple review criterion, I've also seen people claim that `CFBundleDisplayName` must be closely *related* to `CFBundleName`.  For example, it's ok if it's a shortened version of `CFBundleName`, but that they might reject the app if it's unrelated altogether.

I also checked the listing in **Settings.app**, and in iTunes, and I didn't see the **Bundle Name** either of those places.

So, to answer your question, I don't believe this variable is visible to the user (on iOS).

---

**Update:** I have **not**, however, checked whether or not any accessibility features might *speak* this name anywhere.

Also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510132/119114) claims that `CFBundleName` will be the name used in the iTunes App Store URL for your app.  But, see @tc.'s comment/example URL below ...

---

**Update 2**: per @honus's comment below, one *unusual* scenario where `CFBundleName` *can* be shown to the user is if your app has **no** entry for `CFBundleDisplayName` in its Info.plist file.  In that case, `CFBundleName` will be shown under the app icon in SpringBoard.

Comment: Having worked with apps whose target/PRODUCT_NAME/CFBundleName were codenames, I'm pretty sure they're never displayed anywhere "user-visible". The most obvious occurrences are in crash logs or the console log (if the user's installed Xcode/iPCU), though this may just be the executable filename, and obviously the app .ipa itself if the user unzips it. *Generated* App Store URLs use the app name as it appears on the App Store (but is [ignored by itunes.apple.com](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/THE_APP_NAME_IS_UNUSED/id284417350?mt=8)).

Comment: I'm pretty sure CFBundleName is the name that will show up for the app on Springboard if you have no CFBundleDisplayName set.

Comment: @honus, thanks for the info.  You are indeed correct.  Not sure that this is a common scenario, but it's certainly good to know.  Answer updated ... again :)

Comment: I love Apple documentations. They are so good that people have to come here to explain what they mean. If there were no forums like SO we would be screwed.

Comment: Just to confirm this: I wrote an app for my Mom's birthday, and it was my second try, so I called the project MomApp2. That is the product name, and by implication, the bundle name. But the user _never_ sees that name! The bundle display name (Diabelli) is set manually in the Info.plist, and so is the name that appears at the app store (Diabelli's Theme).

Comment: CFBundleName is used in WatchKit apps. It is shown in Apple Watch app on the phone.

Comment: On iOS it is displayed during Google Sign-In as `"${CFBundleName}" name Wants to Use "google.com" to Sign In". This is system dialog, view hierarchy debugger doesn't show it, but I don't know which iOS API does GoogleSignIn framework invoke.

Comment: @SergiiRudchenko correct, it is also used on iOS when asking Facebook SDK to login. I believe it is Safari which presents the dialog.

Comment: It can also affect the `User-Agent` header in network calls, since network implementations can depend on `CFBundleExecutable` or `CFBundleName`, for example Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/030710ebf19bd8178db52cb2d185e5e5fe271241/Source/Core/HTTPHeaders.swift#L383C34-L383C52

Answer (score 14):

It's not well-documented, but `CFBundleName` is displayed to the user in the permission dialog displayed by [ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession).

[image: ASWebAuthenticationSession Dialog Example]

Comment: Well done, very good find!

Comment: It's the right answer, yet it's a very bottom answer

Comment: This is wrong, CFBundleDisplayName this used in permission dialog. not the CFBundleName

Comment: I confirm this, we had found that this dialog is still taking `CFBundleName` in iOS 17

Answer (score 0):

You can access those keys like this.

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

Where `infoDicitonary` is `A dictionary, constructed from the bundle's Info.plist file`. There you can find this sort of information about your App. [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Note: You can check the actual key by opening the `App-info.plist` file and right clicking anywhere then selecting the option `Show Raw Keys/Values`.

Comment: Hi, my question is: If I set this value in the info.plist, how does it mean for normal user? Where they can find this value?

Comment: This only returns the non-localised values, you can use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]` if you want to get the localised value.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-123093

Answer (score 0):

CFBundleName IS used, when localizing a MacOS Cocoa App, in the Mac OS MenuBar as the Application Name (right from the File Menu).
So it DEFINITELY has a meaning.
Don't know, if it is used and shown somewhere else. But better not leave it out, when localizing your app!

Answer (score 0):

On macOS it is used as a means to decide if the application's name should be localized in the Finder. If the actual name of the bundle (of course extended by '.app') matches `CFBundleName`, Finder will show its localized display name instead. However, a user might rename the App to something he finds more appropriate and in that case, macOS needs a way to tell if the name was customized.

Answer (score -1):

If you open your info.plist file by context clicking it in the project tree and selecting "Open As > Source Code", you'll see the XML representation of the plist. By default, these two keys have the same value, so you could access either one.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
```

To actually grab the values, you can use this SO post as a guideline: [How to display the current project version of my App to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492351/how-to-display-the-current-project-version-of-my-app-to-the-user) Just replace the `CFBundleVersion` key with `CFBundleDisplayName`.

In essence:

```
NSString *displayName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] 
                                          valueForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

Comment: Hi, my question is: If I set this value in the info.plist, how does it mean for normal user? Where they can find this value?

Comment: A normal user won't see it unless you display it. You have to decide where you want to display the name. You can add a label to a view or you can display it in a navigation controller. The point is that *you* have to code that. It won't show up anywhere automatically except under the home screen icon.

Comment: After some testing, the one which display under the home screen icon is `CFBundleDisplayName`, not `CFBundleName`

Answer (score -4):

Bundle name is the name of the actual application bundle on the file system.

Bundle display name is the caption of the application icon that the user will see on either their iOS device or the caption of the icon on OSX.

Comment: As I mentioned in my other answer, I've heard people say that, too, but I just built an iOS 5 app, changed **Bundle Name**, and it definitely did not name the `.app` directory with that Bundle Name.

Comment: theres a reason you heard other people say it.

Comment: I just built the app.  It doesn't use the name for the .app folder on iOS 5.  If there's a reason, then the reason is that people can be unreliable sources of information.

Comment: try archiving your app, then exporting it and check the result

Comment: I don't know what you mean by **Export**, but if I **Archive** from Xcode, it shows up in Organizer with a name other than `CFBundleName` (assuming I changed CFBundleName, of course).  If I click on the archive and **Show in Finder**, the .xcarchive file is also **not** named per CFBundleName. If I **Distribute**, and save it as an .ipa, and then unzip that .ipa, the .app folder inside is not named per CFBundleName.

Comment: That's what I just said I did.  See the big bolded word **Archive** above?  CFBundleName on an .app folder absolutely nowhere to be found.

Comment: stackmonster - you are wrong. i just tested and my results are the same as Nate's.

Comment: yeah Im wrong thats why my aps have the exact specified bundleName and bundle display name every time