# Separate BundleName and name shown under app icon

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, cfbundledisplayname

I am trying to submit an App to the app store that annoying has the same name as another product. I have created an App in App Store Connect and the name of your app as it will appear on the App Store is unique.

The name that appears under the app however I believe does not need to be unique. As an example I have 2 chess apps on my device, both that display "Chess" under their icon, but have a different name on the app store.

I have set my `CFBundleDisplayName` as the name I would like to see under the icon, my `CFBundleName` is using a `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` variable.

When I try and validate a build in XCode however I get the error to tell me

> The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already in use

I'd love some pointer on how to achieve this if possible please.

I suspect I'm missing something in my build settings or an additional prop in the `info.plist`

Ideally I'd like to not change the name below the icon as it is a new product in a suite that all follow a pattern of naming.

So I logged out these three values

1. CFBundleDisplayName
2. CFBundleName
3. CFBundleIdentifier

They are all unique, when I change `CFBundleDisplayName` however, validation fails.

[image]

Comment: The name that appears under the app icon on the dashboard need not be unique. However, the bundle identifier and the application name in the App Store connect should be unique.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of my `info.plist` is there another property I should be looking at? Thank you.

Comment: One thing only and that is the **Bundle identifier**.
P.S: Were you able to create an app with the current bundle identifier on the app store connect?

Comment: Are you sure CFBundleName is something unique and not same for both the apps? CFBundleDisplayName can be same for the apps. I am pretty much sure about it. Bcoz, i myself have two apps in appstore with two different bundle name but with same display name.

Comment: You may have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146750/where-cfbundlename-is-being-used) before. If not then you may find it helpful.

Comment: I do have my app created in app store connect already, I am confident the current bundle id should be ok. I must be missing something somewhere :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your display name match an existing core iOS app name?

I don't believe you can name an app anything that matches core iOS apps, for example *Home, Settings* or *Photos* would all be off limits.